# Migration from SQL Server 2008 to Azure

Tags: sql-server-2008, migration, azure-sql-database

I'm using SQLAzureMW v3.8.8 but I get lots of errors in the script generated. And the problem is that i don't know in which line is each error generated.

> Error #: 105 -- Unclosed quotation mark after the character string
>   'CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAdminParametrosGet]
>
> Error #: 156 -- Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.
>
> Error #: 40512 -- Deprecated feature 'NOLOCK or READUNCOMMITTED in
>   UPDATE or DELETE' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.
>
> Incorrect syntax near '

The TSQL script generates sql stored procedures as strings and are created using dynamic SQL. Some stored procedures have comments inside of it.

May that be the cause or any suggestion to quickly migrate the database to Azure?

Comment: This belongs on Database Administrators SE. (http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

It is very much possible that some of the SP and other statements which you want to migrate from SQL Server to SQL Azure are not compatible. Here is a list of supported and unsupported TSQL  features:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336250.aspx

Also you haven't mentioned what is your source SQL Server is? As not all SQL Server will full features are supported by SAMQ (3.8 or 4.01)

Also please match your TSQL statements from the unsupported list below and check if any of listed below are part of your TSQL statements:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336253.aspx